# Exclude a field in Mongoose wile using assignment operator for Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am aware that this question has been asked before. Sites often give the solution using `.select('-queryData')`however I do not know how to use it for my scenario.

I have a DB with the following schema

```
let TestSchema = new Schema ({
..
test: {type: String, required: true},
arrayField: {type: Array, required: true},
..
});
```

I have to query the arrayField where it should not include `'data1'`. If it includes this value then that object should not be shown.

However I am using assignment operator for query object, instead of calling the function `'.select()'`. Hence I tried adding it in the query JSON itself, but it did not work.

**index.js**

```
let query = {};

query.test = "Hello";
query.arrayField = '-data1'; //Change needed here

    TestSchema.find(query, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

I tried checking various sites for a specific solution to such a scenario, however I could not get any conclusive solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $exists mongodb operator for your query.

```
TestModel.find({ test: "Hello", "arrayField.data1": { $exists: false } })
```

Select method has a different use case which is to select or limit the fields returned as a result of a query. And you need to execute find method on TestModel not TestSchema.

```
const TestModel = mongoose.model("TestModel", TestSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `$exists` operator, here's an example:

```
TestModel.find({
    test: "Hello",
    "arrayField.$.data1": {
        $exists: false
    }
}, function(err, result){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```